# Как создать базу данных mdf из кода?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Как создать базу данных mdf из кода?

Запускается программа. после этого нужно создать базу данных. И добавить в неё данные.

```
 public class Context1 : DbContext
{
    //public Context1() : base("Base1") { }
    public Context1(string connection) : base(connection) { }

    public DbSet<AAA> A{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<BBB> B{ get; set; }

}

public static void CreateSqlDatabase(string filename)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=";
        //string connectionString = @"server=(localdb)\v12.0"; //"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=";
        string databaseName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString + filename))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')", databaseName, filename);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", databaseName);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }



CreateSqlDatabase(filename);
```

Так не получается.

```
connection.Open();
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>     HResult=0x80131904
>     Сообщение = При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Указанный экземпляр LocalDB не существует.
>   )
>
> Источник = .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Comment: EntityFramework сам создаст базу. Не нужно ее создавать вручную.

Comment: а пример?......

Comment: Выполните _любой_ запрос с помощью своего `Context1` - база создастся.

Comment: не создаётся `  Сообщение = No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
  Источник = EntityFramework`